# When select first kendo multiselect dropdown item,second kendo multiselect dropdown items automatically selected.

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I have two multi select kendo dropdown

Ist dropdown is

```
<label class="control-label required">Site Name1</label>
                            <select kendo-multi-select id="Site_ids" ng-disabled="ctrl.viewSpecLic" ng-required="ctrl.Iscreate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.records"
                                    k-options="ctrl.list" name="prvSite_ids" style="width:200px"></select>
```

2nd dropdown is,

```
<label class="control-label">Specialty1</label>
                                <select kendo-multi-select id="spec2" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.recordId2"
                                        k-options="ctrl.list2" name="Sp_muli_Splty_ids" style="width:200px"></select>
                           </li>
```

**Problem:**
When i select 1st dropdown item,the 2nd dropdown items is automatically selected.

1. This issue happened both IE and chrome browser.
2. I have tested another system with same version browser.Here multi dropdown is working fine.

Please let me know you have any idea.

Comment: Can you create a DOJO/CodePen that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only happend only clicked on the checkbox .Other wise its working fine.